# how to rewind to a previous loop in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a screen with a training session, I have a multidimensional array, where I have a list of exercises and inside a list of sets for each exercise. During the passage of each set I have the sequence of a loop with a timer and a countdown. what I intend to do is to be able to go back to a previous loop, when the user presses a button to go back. How can I do this?

**below is the class with the loops mentioned above.**

```
Stream<TrainingEvent> start() async* {
    yield StartEvent();
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
for (TrainingSession trainingSession in trainingTimers) {
      for (int sets = trainingSession.sets.length; sets > 0; sets--) {
        if (trainingSession.typeSet != "T") {
          //CountUp
          timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
            seconds++;
            if (seconds > 59) {
              minutes++;
              seconds = 0;
            }
            if (minutes == 60) {
              timer.cancel();
            }
          });
          while (timer!.isActive) {
            yield ExerciseEvent(
              training: trainingSession,
              timer: timer,
              minutes: minutes,
              seconds: seconds,
              countDown: false,
              completeSet: completeSets,
            );
            await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
          }
          seconds = trainingSession.rest;
          minutes = 0;
        }
        //CountDown
        timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
          seconds--;

          if (seconds == 0) {
            timer.cancel();
          }
        });
        while (timer!.isActive) {
          yield ExerciseEvent(
            training: trainingSession,
            timer: timer,
            minutes: minutes,
            seconds: seconds,
            countDown: true,
            completeSet: completeSets,
          );
          await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
        }
        int index = trainingSession.sets.length - sets;

        completeSets.add(trainingSession.sets[index]);
        yield ExerciseEvent(
            training: trainingSession,
            minutes: minutes,
            seconds: seconds,
            countDown: true,
            completeSet: completeSets);
      }
    }
yield EndEvent();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would say you need to use a better state management rather than having a single stream. Something like Bloc or a ViewModel would simplify this issue a lot. Next thing is that this function is way too big, you really have to split it into smaller functions. It doesn't make sense that this function has a periodic timer, but then also a `await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));`

Take a look at [this medium post](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-timer-with-flutter-bloc-a464e8332ceb) on how to create a simple timer. Here you can see that the triggering of an event results in a state.

```dart
  Stream<TimerState> mapEventToState(
    TimerEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is Start) {
      yield* _mapStartToState(event);
    } else if (event is Pause) {
      yield* _mapPauseToState(event);
    } else if (event is Tick) {
      yield* _mapTickToState(event);
    }
  }
```

You'll need to keep track of the current `trainingSessionIndex` and when a session is completed, increase this index. When you press the back button decrease the index.

This also will yield in a new state with that `trainingSession` and the corresponding sets.